# When starting VS Code from the CLI, can I make the workspace trusted without disabling workspace trust for the whole session?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing a script that runs VS Code in a temporary directory. In order to start VS Code, my script runs `code -w -n the_directory`. As this is a newly created temporary directory, it's definitely trusted, but I still get the prompt "Do you trust the owners of this workspace?"

Is there a command line flag to say that yes, I do trust the directory I'm opening? I couldn't see one in the output of `code --help`, or in the docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line.

I found [the flag `--disable-workspace-trust`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_commandline-switchh), but that's not really what I want. It will disable workspace trust for all workspaces opened in that VS Code session, whereas I still want trust enabled if I close the initially opened workspace without ending the VS Code session an open a different workspace folder. It's like running an elevated command prompt for an extended period, which is a risk I'd rather avoid.

Comment: then close VSC and open the other workspace